# Choosing compromise between pull vs push based notification

Tags: optimization, push-notification, architecture

I am trying to find a solution for the following problem.

I have a number of `N` clients (the number is fixed somewhere between `5000` and `6000` ) and a `Server`.

This server has a local `cache` of clients where it stores some data for each client.

```
public class Client
{
  public bool inGroup; 
}
```

This server queries some database periodically and gets a list of these `clients` and it updates its local cache. Whenever it finds discrepancies (the client data is just a `bool` )between the `cache` and the fresh data from the db it has to inform the specific clients.

Now I do not know if I should implement a `PULL` or a `PUSH` based solution.
If choosing the `PULL` then it means every client would interrogate the server at a fixed interval somewhere near 30 minutes. That would mean `30 / 6000 = 300 ms` between each request.

If choosing the `PUSH` based solution it would mean the server would interrogate the database at timed intervals and only push to specific clients. Now the problem with this would be that each client would also become a server, so the server has to also store a table of  `IP`-s and `Ports`.

The clients working hours are also similar so this would also mean at target hours there would be spikes where each client would send its `IP` and `PORT` for the server to check if it was modified.

Is there any other middle solution ? And if not what would a good solution be considering:

- Number of clients is pretty constant (5000-6000)
- Clients `IP` and `PORT` don't usually change.
- Clients would query the server once per 30 min if Pull Based
- Server would query database at every 1 min and push to target clients if Push based

Answer (score 1):

The middle solution would be using [long polling](https://www.ably.io/concepts/long-polling). The client still issues a poll request and server returns it immediately if there is notification waiting for this client. But if there is no notification the request is blocked for some time (let's say two minutes). If there is new notification during this time then the client request is unblocked and the new data is returned. Otherwise the request returns an empty result after two minute timeout and issues a new request.

This is approach used by a lot of high scale services like [AWS SQS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-long-polling.html).